# Are NUL and NULL interchangeable in C?

Tags: c++, c

Just read pointer on C book by Kenneth Reek. It says that a NUL byte is one whose bits are all 0, written like this `'\0'` and NULL has a value 0 which refers to a pointer whose value is zero.

> Both are integers and have the same value, so they could be used interchangeably.

and this code also:

```
char const *keyword[] = { "do", "for", "if", "register", 
                              "return", "switch", "while", NULL };
```

In this code, the NULL lets functions that search the table detect the end of the table. So, can we interchange NULL and NUL macros?

Comment: Have you tried it? You generally use `'\0'` for characters in strings, and `NULL` or `nullptr` for pointers.

Comment: *so they could be used interchangeably* horrible advice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`NUL` is the notation for an ASCII character code 0.

`NULL` is a macro defined in **[`stddef`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/)** for the null pointer.

So, *no*, they are not to be used interchangeably.

Comment: NULL has the size of a pointer (typically 32 or even 64 bits).
NUL has the size of a character (typically 8 bits in C, and sometimes 16 in other languages that support 16-bit Unicode).
They can't be used interchangeably.  If you're using a 0 in a string, it's NUL.  If you're using a 0 in a pointer, it's NULL.
Only NULL has a macro in C.  In C, all literal strings get a NUL 0 byte appended at the end automatically by the compiler, so there's no need for a macro.

Comment: @nonrectangular "NULL has the size of a pointer" --> maybe.  It might have the size of an `int`.  The _type_ of `NULL` is not specified.

Answer (score 14):

There is no standardized `NUL` macro, at least not  in C.

Also, `NULL` has the advantage over a plain `0` literal that it signals to the reader that "hey, we're dealing with a pointer" which might be considered an advantage.

In C++, the idiom was for a long while to just write `0`, but then they seem to have reversed that and introduced a new literal, `nullptr` for some reason(s).

In C, I recommend writing `NULL` for pointers and `'\0'` for characters.

Comment: Even stronger, avoid using `NULL` for characters, because if your code ever becomes C++11, being able to search-and-replace `NULL` with `nullptr` gives you extra type safety.  And every use of `NULL` for the integer constant zero that isn't a pointer will make this harder.

Comment: the reason for nullptr is that its a void * pointer. NULL in C is not. So the 'some reason' is for type safety