# I can't store a string of characters in a node of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm doing my coursework regarding airport simulation and I'm having some troubles trying to store information in the character array part.

I am supposed to type in a string of character and it will store in the `planeName` part of the node but it can't seem to work. My `int main()` is pretty much empty now because I didn't want to continue coding with incorrect functions.

Below are my codes:

```
struct node {
    char planeName[5];
    int planeNumber;
    struct node* next;
}; 

struct node* front = NULL;
struct node* rear = NULL;

void Enqueue(char name[5], int x);

int main() {

}

void Enqueue(char name[5], int x){

    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp -> planeName = name; 
    temp -> planeNumber = x;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
        front = rear = temp;
    rear -> next = temp; //set address of rear to address of temp
    rear = temp; //set rear to point to temp

    return;
}
```

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn67j.png) in the line containing: `temp -> planeName = name`

This is the part where error message pops up and I have no clue why is this happening.

Can someone please help and ask more questions me if my question is not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you are performing a *shallow copy* by copying the name of your array `planeName`.

If you want to copy your array you need to copy each and every element of it, this is done easier if the last element of your array contains a special character indicating its end, for example the character `\0`.

An array containing as its last character, the `\0` is called: *null terminated*. There are a lot of functions that perform operations on null terminated arrays. The one that you need is:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

which will copy all of the element of the null terminated array passed as `source` to `destination`. In your case it will look like this:

```
strcpy(temp -> planeName,name);
```

---

Here is a brief info about [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

Comment: Thanks! This is very detailed answer! One question, it might sound silly but  do I have to explicitly write '\0' in my input?

Comment: @KateLee No, if you take input using `scanf` then statement could be `scanf("%4s",name);` and if you use `fgets`  it will be added to `name` automatically.

Comment: @Kate Lee Glad that I could help!

Comment: @ameyCU  Gratitudes to for the clarifications!

Answer (score 5):

```
temp -> planeName = name;
```

You can't assign to an array. Array cannot be used as lvalue. Use `strcpy` instead-

```
strcpy(temp -> planeName,name);
```

**Note**- But make sure your `char` arrays are nul terminated before passing them to `strcpy`.

Comment: Hi! Forgive my ignorance but what is nul terminated? I'm a fairly new programmer hence I'm unsure of some technical terms.

Comment: @KateLee  [I would suggest you to take a look here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479335/is-nul-and-null-interchangeable-in-c) . This will clear between `NULL` and `NUL`.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are arrays of characters, so you have to copy the individual elements.  Fortunately, there are functions (like strcpy) written to do just that.